# is this js coding style have affect to file size

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have some condition:

**first**

```
import React from 'react'
...
//what i used 
class Whatever extends React.Component{
}
Whatever.propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

or

```
import React,{Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
...
//what i used 
class Whatever extends Component {
}
Whatever.propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

Is that impact to filesize after i bundled it using webpack/other development tools.

**second**
Sometimes I used it in some function in same class

```
function mama()
{
    const {name, age} = this.state
}
```

and this one

```
function mama()
{
    const name = this.state.name 
    const age = this.state.age
}
```

Any body know why other code have small size than others, and why?
Or they have the same size?
I used webpack to bundling my js to single file.

Thanks.

Comment: The differences will be negligible, especially after minification and gzipping. In fact, gzip might perform better if the content contains more repeating patterns. You should aim for making your code readable. Leave file size optimization to tools.

Comment: You should focus on making your logic short and your code readable instead of worrying too much reducing size on minor things like this

Comment: very constructive answer, thank you